# getJSON() - how to remove AND-sign in front of data param?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I'm doing the following jQuery call:

```
$.getJSON(
"http://localhost:9000/user?name=",
"test",
function(data) {
alert(data.aaData[0]);}
);
```

but it doesn't work because the data param "test" will be "&test" in the actual call (at least that's what firebug tells me).

I'm a total beginner with JavaScript and jQuery, can anyone tell me how to remove the &-sign in front of the data param?
So that the actual call is `http://localhost:9000/user?name=data` and not `http://localhost:9000/user?name=&data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the data as an object, like this:

```
$.getJSON(
    "http://localhost:9000/user",
    { name: "test" },
    function(data) {
        alert(data.aaData[0]);
    }
);
```

The data-object will then be converted to a string and URL-encoded before it is added to the URL. From the [jQuery documentation of `.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> If the value of the data parameter is an object (map), it is converted
>   to a string and url-encoded before it is appended to the URL.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the get variables to be sent in the correct way:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:9000/user", "name=test", function(data) {
    alert(data.aaData[0]);
});
```